# how to know the ID of the inserted row

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, relational-database

i have a table contains two colomns , the first is an ID and the second is text , like this

```
oneContent (ID,contentText)
```

i have another table

```
ioContents (IOID,oneContentID)
```

and i want to insert this message (" hi man i am WilliamRoma") into the oneContent and then link it in the ioContents to the IOID =3

i can do that by inserting the message first in the oneContent table and then insert its ID to the ioContents , but how can i get its ID ? ? ? ,

one way to doing it is

```
SELECT ID FROM oneContent WHERE contentText = "hi man i am WilliamRoma"
```

but this is a bad way i think , what do u suggest that after inserting the message ,get its id?

ever ID is auto increment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

I think you want `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: but i am working on a server so maybe the last insert id will be from another client , right ?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: Nope.  Call it within the same transaction scope and it will return what was in that scope.

Comment: To quote the manual: "For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client."

Comment: @fulhack but just one think please , i will use it in a loop , i mean i will insert the message in the loop and withing the same loop before changing the I value i will used ur statement , it will work right ?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. I would assume that would work, but you would have to try it for yourself ;)

Comment: @fulhack i got this error message Fatal error: Call to undefined function LAST_INSERT_ID() , i am using PDO , phpmyadmin 1.7.4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11475/discussion-between-fulhack-and-william-kinaan)